# Is it possible to set fix process ID for android application?

Tags: java, android, c

I am creating a softkeyboard for android to play around with ptrace(). I would like to set a fix process id for the application I made. Is it possible to to it so that I can play around android app with ptrace()?

Comment: You could `fork()` in a loop checking `getpid()`, until you get the pid you want and hope another process on the system isn't using it. :) (Better would be to find the pid of your process _after_ you have started it, and attach to that.)

Comment: Yes, you should do as sarnold says. You can find the PID programmatically by executing the **ps** shell command and filtering the output based on the package name of your app.

Comment: I have tried that, but I would like to fix the program, not need to keep changing it... Therefore I want to fix the process id. I want to use it in the android phone itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this.  The usual approach is to have your application write its process ID to a file when it starts up; the other application can then read that file.

Comment: +1. Bao, what you're asking for doesn't make sense. Let's such a functionality exists. What should happen if the PID is in use? Should your program be prevented from running? Should the current program using the PID be killed? Neither option seems very reasonable. If such a feature existed, mayhem would certainly ensure quickly on that operating system.

Comment: Agree. Does not make any sense to fix the process id for an application. Its the OS's decision to assign the PID to a process, and that should remain like that in larger interest of user space!